# Can I import and save each event in a public google calendar to my asp.net mvc database?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, fullcalendar, google-calendar-api, fullcalendar-3

I'm working in asp.net mvc, and am trying to display all events from any public google calendar in the fullCalendar I've built for my application. Currently, I'm displaying a users events that are saved in the database under an Events model, as well as in that users list of events. I have a button on the view displaying their calendar that says "Sync My Google Calendar". What I want to do is have them input their Calendar ID to pass into a SyncGoogleCalendar() method. From there I'll save each event to the databases. Then I can display all events from their google calendar, as well as all the events they created in my application on one calendar. 
Would this be possible? I know fullCalendar has a way to display the events in the calendar but that hasn't been working so far....I'll keep playing with it until I get any suggestions, but thanks in advance for anyone willing to comment!

Comment: What does your code look like that doesn't work? Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: if your end goal is to display the events from the google calendar within fullCalendar, you can display events from a google calendar directly into fullCalendar without importing them in your database first. https://fullcalendar.io/docs/google_calendar/